# Ordering a listarray algorithm

Tags: java, arraylist, mergesort

**EDIT:**

So I actually figured out the problem.. at first index range was out of bounds because for my while-loop, I did not set `counter = 0` in the event that `charB2 > charA2`. However, for some reason using `++counter` in my index loops the program indefinitely. Therefore, I did a small fix:

Sorry if this seemed like an unnecessary post from the start however, after posting my question I was getting a lot of different feedback that made me try alternatives I would not have thought otherwise.

```
    int c = 1;

    while (charA2 == charB2) {

        charA = a.charAt(c);
        charB = b.charAt(c);
        c++;

        charA2 = charA;
        charB2 = charB;
        if (charA2 > charB2) {
            merged.set(j, b);
            merged.set(j + 1, a);
        }
```

So I am given two string listarrays in java and I need to write a method without using Collections.sort to combine the two lists and sort them.

```
public static ArrayList<String> merged(ArrayList<String> lst1, ArrayList<String> lst2) {

    int size = lst1.size() + lst2.size();
    ArrayList<String> merged = new ArrayList<String>(size);

    merged.addAll(lst1);
    merged.addAll(lst2);

    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < merged.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < merged.size() - 1; j++) {
            String a = merged.get(j);
            String b = merged.get(j + 1);

            Character charA = a.charAt(counter);
            Character charB = b.charAt(counter);

            int charA2 = charA;
            int charB2 = charB;

            if (charA2 > charB2) {
                merged.set(j, b);
                merged.set(j + 1, a);
            } else
            if (charA2 == charB2) {
                while (charA2 == charB2) {
                    charA = a.charAt(++counter);
                    charB = b.charAt(++counter);

                    charA2 = charA;
                    charB2 = charB;
                    if (charA2 > charB2) {
                        merged.set(j, b);
                        merged.set(j + 1, a);
                        counter = 0;
                    } else {
                        counter=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return merged;
 }
```

My method was basically converting the string at the same index into a character which then I can convert into an int-value and if the integer value for the current element is greater than the next, I swap them.

So I figured that if I just iterate the list and compare each element to its following element, I can eventually sort it but for some reason I run into an error that says index range out of bound for when `charA2 == charB2`.

Comment: It seem you want to implement the mergesort, but that is not how the mergesort works.

Comment: well my professor said we cannot use any methods that sort the list so we can use any methods except that

Comment: Are you allowed to compare strings using their `.compareTo(String other)` method?

Comment: Yes.. but i am not familiar with .campareTo.. I can look it up right now

Comment: I just looked up the compareTo.. but it takes the entire string which may assign a higher value to a string that is alphabetically less than its counterpart

Comment: @swordlordswamplord _"well my professor said we cannot use any methods that sort the list"_ and you dont have to use any other sort method. You should revisit the part of your lecture where the mergesort is discussed and look for a pseudocode or look some online up.

Comment: oh yes. I remember that section and it was to compare an element or key to a list.. using that didnt occur to me

Comment: @swordlordswamplord _"it takes the entire string"_ as it should to compare and in your case sort a list of strings. If you think it would not compare correctly to the specificytions of your task you should put that also in your question.

Comment: well I can simply check my answer by comparing a string lets say "azzzz" to "baaa" and see what happens when I compare the two. I never used compareTo method before but I am guessing it will return "baaa"

Comment: @swordlordswamplord _"I am guessing it will return `"baaa"`"_ why do you think that? `"azzzz".compareTo("baaa")` will return -1 which means that `"azzzz"` is less than `"baaa"`

Comment: `.compareTo()` reflects the lexicographical ordering of strings, so unless you have a good reason to not use the lexicographical ordering to sort the list of strings use `.compareTo()` instead of writing your own method to compare string. Or is it part of the exercie?

Answer (score 0):

Your merging method makes no assumption about the initial ordering of `lst1` and `lst2`: you add all elements from both lists to the `merged` array at the beginning and try and perform insertion sort on the resulting array.

You can simplify your code if you can use the `compareTo` method on strings:

```java
public static ArrayList<String> merged(ArrayList<String> lst1, ArrayList<String> lst2) {

    int size = lst1.size() + lst2.size();
    ArrayList<String> merged = new ArrayList<String>(size);

    merged.addAll(lst1);
    merged.addAll(lst2);

    for (int i = size; i-- > 0;) {
        bool swapped = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            String a = merged.get(j);
            String b = merged.get(j + 1);
            if (a.compareTo(b) > 0) {
                merged.set(j, b);
                merged.set(j + 1, a);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (!swapped)
            break;
    }
    return merged;
}
```

If you the lists `lst1 and`lst2`are known to be sorted, you can use a much more efficient method to merge these into`merged`, probably covered in your course on`mergesort`:

```java
public static ArrayList<String> merged(ArrayList<String> lst1, ArrayList<String> lst2) {
    // assuming lst1 and lst2 are already sorted
    int size1 = lst1.size();
    int size2 = lst2.size();
    ArrayList<String> merged = new ArrayList<String>(size1 + size2);

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < size1 && j < size2) {
        String a = lst1.get(i);
        String b = lst2.get(j);
        if (a.compareTo(b) <= 0) {
            merged.set(k++, a);
            i++;
        } else {
            merged.set(k++, b);
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (i < size1) {
        merged.set(k++, lst1.get(i++));
    }
    while (j < size2) {
        merged.set(k++, lst2.get(j++));
    }
    return merged;
}
```